# How to run one BigQuery query and then group_by multiple fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I work with BigQuery/Python and have a SELECT query which takes ~3 seconds.
After I run the query, I would like to do group_by 8 different fields.
For example:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
FROM ....
GROUP BY A

SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
FROM ....
GROUP BY B

SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H
FROM ....
GROUP BY C
```

The question is how can I run the SELECT only once and then run GROUP_BY 8 times for a different fields.
I know that in Django, for example, it's possible when using annotate in ORM:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate

But how it can be done with BiqQuery?

Maybe there is some good python ORM that can help me with that?

Comment: If you use Python, an alternative is to download all the data into a Pandas dataframe, and let Pandas handle the groupings.

Comment: Yes. That's what I did eventually. But the question is if there is a way to do it on the DB side. Annotation is just one of the examples. In general it will be nice to have some solution for concatenating queries...

Comment: examples you show in your question are oversimplified thus missing some important info - what kind of aggregations you do for the rest of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

While it might not be elegant, you can make generous use of CTEs.

```
with data as ( 
    select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H from <dataset>.<table>
),
groupA as (
    select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, 'A' as my_grouping from data group by 1
),
groupB as (
    select A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, 'B' as my_grouping from data group by 2
),
....etc
unioned as (
    select * from groupA  UNION ALL
    select * from groupB  UNION ALL
    ...etc
)
select * from unioned
```

Then you can easily use the results by selecting a `my_grouping`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

I assume that you have below as a result of your first query (simplified version of your example)

```
WITH initial_select_result AS (
  SELECT 1 a, 1 b, 1 c, 1 x UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 a, 2 b, 2 c, 2 x UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 a, 2 b, 3 c, 3 x  
)
```

and now I assume that you want to group by each column [a, b, c] and for each of such grouping you want to do SUM(x)

The simple straightforward way to do so - is as in below query

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 'a' key, a value, SUM(x) x_sum FROM initial_select_result GROUP BY a UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', b, SUM(x) FROM initial_select_result GROUP BY b UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', c, SUM(x) FROM initial_select_result GROUP BY c
```

This approach requires knowledge of all such column name and have an extra line for each such column with respective use of column name.

Below approach is more generic and avoid explicit mentioning of column names (but still requires aggregated column name to be explicitly called out)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT key, value, SUM(x) x_sum
FROM initial_select_result t,
UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'("\w+":\w+)')) kv, 
UNNEST([STRUCT(REPLACE(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"', '') AS key, SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS value)])
GROUP BY key, value
HAVING NOT key = 'x'
```

Both above solutions give below result

```
Row key value   x_sum    
1   a   1       6    
2   b   1       1    
3   b   2       5    
4   c   1       1    
5   c   2       2    
6   c   3       3
```